# Unsubscribe não funciona no RXJS, qual o método correto de uso?

Tags: angular, nativescript, rxjs, angular-8

Fiz um código para monitorar um Mapa usando o *nativescript-geolocation* e o *nativescript-google-maps-sdk*, há um serviço do Angular que encapsula toda a lógica de acesso ao *nativescript-geolocation* que recebe um subscribe fornecido por um comente do Angular.

Ao executar o listener representado pela função `componente.mapViewRead()`, que é executado quando o mapa está pronto, este cadastra no serviço o subscribe chamando um método `servico.gpsInfo$.subscribe((gpsInfo)=>this.gpsInfo = gpsInfo)`, quando o usuário manipula o mapa mudando a posição da camera para uma nova coordenada, uma propriedade que representa o *subscripition* é usada por outro listener responsável pela manipulação da camera para desativar o subscribe chamando a função `this.subscription.unsubscribe()`.

Apesar da subscrição ser desativada teóricamente e poder ser constado através da propriedade `this.subscription.isClosed`, ele não para de processar as chamadas do Observable.

Será que eu estou fazendo algo errado? ou é um bug do RXJS?

Abaixo está o código de ambos serviço e componente.

[Neste link](https://github.com/islamic-works/mussala-module/blob/master/compass.service.ts) pode ser encontrado o código completo do serviço, e abaixo o código relevante ao problema.

```
startHeadingUpdates() {
        if (this.watchId) {
            return;
        }

        this.watchId = geoLocation.watchLocation(
            (loc) => {
                if (loc) {
this._gpsInfo.next(<GPSInfo>loc);
                }
            },
            (e) => {
                console.error("Error: " + e.message);
            },
            { desiredAccuracy: 3, updateDistance: 10, minimumUpdateTime: 1000 * .3 });
    }
    public get gpsInfo(): Observable<GPSInfo> {
        if (!this._gpsInfo$)
            this._gpsInfo$ = this._gpsInfo.asObservable()
        return this._gpsInfo$;
    }
```

Código completo do componente pode ser encontrado [neste link](https://github.com/islamic-works/mussala-module/blob/master/mussala-maps/mussala-maps.components.ts), abaixo apenas o código relevante ao problema:

```
// componente
    private subscribeGPSInfo() {
        this._gpsInfoSubscription = this._compass.gpsInfo.subscribe((gpsInfo) => {
            this.gpsInfo = gpsInfo;
        }, (error) => {         console.error("MussalaMapsComponent.ngAfterViewInit() _compass.gpsInfo.subscribe ", error);
        });
    }

    private unsubscribeGPSInfo() {
        if (this._gpsInfoSubscription && this._gpsInfoSubscription.closed) {
        this._gpsInfoSubscription.unsubscribe();
        }
    }

    goToMyLocation() {
        const cfg: GPSConfig = {};
        this._compass.getMyLocation(cfg)
            .then((gpsInfo: GPSInfo) => {
                this.gpsInfo = gpsInfo;
                this.mapView.latitude = this.gpsInfo.latitude;
                this.mapView.longitude = this.gpsInfo.longitude;
            });

        this.subscribeGPSInfo();
    }
    onMapReady(event) {
        const template = this.createInfoWindowTemplate();
        this.mapView.infoWindowTemplates = template;

        let marker: Marker = this._compass.createIslamicMarker(
            1,
            MakerType.MUSSALA,
            "Mussala Fortaleza",
            "Fortaleza, Ce, Brasil",
            "Rua São Paulo, 1831 - Jacarecanga, Fortaleza - CE, 60310-226",
            //-3.7214696,-38.5430259
            <GPSInfo>{ latitude: -3.7214696, longitude: -38.5430259 }
        );
        this.mapView.addMarker(marker);

        marker = this._compass.createIslamicMarker(
            2,
            MakerType.SPONSOR,
            "Curso Arduino Minas",
            "Aquiraz, Ce, Brasil",
            "R. José Alves Pereira, S/N, Aquiraz, CE, Brasil",
            {
                latitude: -3.9242100850690402,
                longitude: -38.45365650951862
            }
        );

        this.mapView.addMarker(marker);

        this.goToMyLocation();
        this.subscribeGPSInfo();

        this.isBusy = false;

    }
```

Comment: Não encontrei no seu código onde unsubscribeGPSInfo é chamado.

Comment: está depois da chamada a função goToMyLocation() no final do código apresentado.

Comment: @paulo-antonelli o problema é na versão do RXJS, há uma versão que tem este bug, mudei para versão anterior e resolveu o problema. Acabei perdendo o link da solução.

Answer (score 1):

Na minha experiência com rxjs ele sempre dá problemas cm unsubscribe dependendo do contexto. Eu resolvo esses problemas criando uma variável e tipando ela com o tipo Subscription do rxjs e todo observable que vou querer garantir o unsubscribe eu atribuo a chamada do subscribe a essa variável e quando eu preciso fazer o unsubscribe basta dar I'm .unsubscribe() na variável topada cm Subscription que interrompe o observable na hora.
Ex:

export class AppComponent {
 public inscricao: Subscription;

escutadorDados(){
    this.incricao = this.entradaDadosService.subscribe(
    (dado) => ...;
 );
}
InterromperEscutadorDados() {
If(this.inscricao){
   this.inscricao.unsubscribe()
}
}
}